# Sending StreamMessage from CMS to JMS

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, activemq-cpp

I am trying to send an ActiveMQ `StreamMessage` from a C++ (CMS) client to a Java (JMS) client.  However, the Java client is unable to correctly read the values from the incoming message - most fields are extracted as `null`, and the fields that do have values associated with them just seem to contain garbage.

I can send `BytesMessages` and `TextMessages` from our C++ client to our Java client just fine, so the `BytesMessage` is our fallback for now.
However, the misbehaving `StreamMessage` is making us suspect something is wrong/incompatible between our two clients.

We are using ActiveMQ 5.4.2 on the Java side, and activemq-cpp 3.0.1 on the C++ side.

Are there any known incompatibilities between the JMS and CMS implementations, or are there any other obvious pitfalls I should look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there were some issues that I fixed somewhere between 3.0.1 and the latest 3.2.4 that fixed some issues with stream message.  I'd really recommend that you update to v3.2.4 of CMS as there's been a large number of bugs fixed, along with some great new features.

The CMS issue tracker is [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQCPP) if you want to review to issues fixed since the version you are using:

Edit: Found the issue that fixed it, its [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQCPP-265).

-Tim

www.fusesource.com

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  I've downloaded 3.2.4 and I'm building it now.

Comment: I'm using the new library now and sending StreamMessages like it's 1999.  ;)